# Passing an argument into sqlalchemy query, displaying tables data dynamically

Tags: sqlalchemy, arguments

I am trying to implement a data tables that will show all EMPLOYEE data for 3 tables but I am having issue displaying the data dynamically if triggered by employee.id. I'm trying to get my head aorund this. Any help will be appreciated

`

```html
@bp.route('/employees/show_all/<int:id>')
@login_required
def show_table(id):

       success = db.session.query(Employee, Passport, Cerpac).\
   select_from(Employee).join(Passport).join(Cerpac).filter(Employee.id==id).all()
    return render_template('admin/employees/show-card.html', show_table=show_table,  title="Show all Employee" )   
    
    
--------------------THE LINK------------------------------
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.show_table', id=employee.id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5">view</a>   
  
  
  --------------------HTML ------------------------------
  
              {% for employee, passport, cerpac in success %}
                <tr>
                  <td>   Employeees  </td>
                  <td> {{ employee.first_name }} </td>
                  <td> {{ employee.last_name }} </td>


                  ----------------------------------------
                  <td>   Cerpac  </td>
                  <td> cerpac.cerpac_serial_no}} </td>
                  <td> {{ cerpac.cerpac_issue_date}} </td>


                  -----------------------------------------
                  <td>   Passport  </td>
                  <td> {{ passport.nationality }} </td>
                  <td> {{ pasport.passport_no }} </td>

                  ------------------------------------------
```

Comment: A few questions to help us answer this: What do you mean with "if triggered by employee.id"? Can you provide some example data & model for the tables? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: I mean I want to display the above tables by employee.id

Comment: Do you mean filtering by id or grouping by id or sorting by id?... It is still pretty vague. In order to avoid any misunderstandings or misinterpretations you should add some sample data with an expected outcome. It will remove all doubt.